# Reading a subset of data from an unkown sized input : memory usage with particular syntax. (Reservoir sampling)

Tags: java, memory, sampling

writting this :

```
N = args[1].split("\\s+").length;
```

with commandline argument like : `echo "A B C D E F G H I" | java Subset 3` , will this consume similar memory as would have been the case if i parsed the `"A B C D E F G H I"` string using `.split()` into a String array ?

my assingment states that (as a challenge) the student (me) can try to display K strings ( K = 3 in the above cmd line ) uniformly at random , from the N string ( N = 9 above , A to I ) input , while consuming memory proportional to K , and not N.
so thats basically what im trying to do.

**edit:** mvp's answer helps out a lot . understand the problem better now.

but i feel i should add that im only allowed to use this :

`private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(System.in), charsetName);`

i cant use the `Scanner` class on my own , or `BufferedReader` for that matter. I'm a bit unsure about how to proceed given this restriction.

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved for input data stream of unknown length (that is, we stop on EOF only, and don't care what N is), and will use memory proportional to K.

For start, let's solve it for K=1. If we start reading input stream, we should assume that first item (A in your example) should be our answer - because if there will be no input, that must be it. When we read second item, we should consider taking it as our answer instead of A with probability `1/2`. When we read 3rd item C, we should take it with probability `1/3`, and so on. This algorithm will randomly select 1 item from input stream without knowing number of items upfront (each item will have equal probability to be chosen).

For K=2, K=3 (or more), we employ similar approach. For example for K=3, read 3 items `A`, `B`, `C` and use them as answer. When we read 4th item, we should select it with probability of `3/4` (K/N) and use it to replace one of the active items with equal probability of `1/3`. Then continue doing that until EOF of input stream, and finally print 3 active items.

Comment: really helps :) but given the restrictions that i cant use Scanner or BufferedReader on my own , do you think its still doable in the above process ? i ask this as `EOF` mainly hits me as C. returning `null` is the same as `EOF` right ?

Comment: @SomjitNag: [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class is perfectly acceptable for your purposes in spirit of this solution. You should use `Scanner.next()` to get next item, and `hasNext()` as EOF marker.

Comment: i dont use scanner too much so wasnt familiar with it. thanks a lot for the help. ill try them out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will use the same because a `String[]` array is created anyways as result of `split`, even if you don't explicitly store it anywhere.

I would suggest you to extract words from the input in the following way:

1. Create a `List wordList` to store the 3 words.
2. Generate a random number between 0 and the length of the input minus 1.
3. If the position corresponding to the random number is whitespace, generate new random numbers until the position is not whitespace.
4. Using the last random number as a starting point, go back in the input searching for a whitespace or the start of the input.  This (+1) defines the start of a word.
5. Using the same random number as a starting point again, go forward in the input searching for a whitespace or the end of the input.  This (-1) defines the end of a word.
6. If this word is already in `wordList`, discard it and repeat from step 2.
7. If not, add it to the list.
8. If the size of the list is less than 3, also repeat from step 2.
9. Print the list.

During this process, you have stored in memory only 3 words (K), not 9 (N).

Scanning can also be performed in the following way:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class MyProgram {
        public static void main(String... args) {
            final int K= 3 ;
            String[] words= new String[K] ;
            int wordCount= 0 ;
            int nextWord= 0 ;
            Scanner scanner= new Scanner(System.in) ;
            while( scanner.hasNext() ) {
                String word= scanner.next();
                wordCount++;
                if( nextWord < K ) {
                    words[nextWord]= word ;
                    nextWord++;
                } else {
                    int replacePos= (int)(Math.random()*wordCount) ; 
                    if( replacePos < K ) {
                        words[replacePos]= word ;
                    }
                }
            }
            scanner.close();
            for(String word: words ) {
                System.out.println(word);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I might have used `List` but im bound to api constraints. Regarding the algorithm you provide , at first sight , it felt like a word-counting algorithm i read in **K&R**. I was searching for a java version of sscanf in C to read from the String. Im really not familiar with the Scanner class.

Comment: @SomjitNag  You don't need to use the `Scanner` class.  You just need to use `String` method `charAt` and numeric indices that move backward and forward by decrementing (`i--`) and incrementing (`i++`).  You can emulate a `List` by using an array and a numeric index to the next available (non-used) element.

Comment: regarding ` int replacePos= (int)(Math.random()*wordCount) ; ` ,  are you sure this is a uniformly random way of doing things ? 
my concern arises from [this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/the-danger-of-naivete.html) link by Jeff Atwood.

Comment: @SomjitNag: The problems have little relationship (as algotithms go), and the algorithms themselves are very different.  I "developed it long ago" and was very surprised to found out it was already known as the best solution.  Why don't you try it?  I could have made a typying error.  And you too! :-)

Comment: @SomjitNag  Yes, I am sure `int replacePos= (int)(Math.random()*wordCount) ;` selects words with `K / totalWordCount` probability **when it is followed by `if( replacePos < K )`**.  In other words, the first expression does not work *alone*, but together with the following `if`.  Again, why don't you try it?  Or do you expect **me** to to it?

Comment: Nah :) only had a problem understanding the echo and pipe part. that being done, things fell in place real quick :)

Answer (score 1):

@mvp has a correct solution for case K = 1, but when K > 1 the correct probability to take item M is K/M, not 1/M (in your case, you should select the 4th item with probability 3/4, the 5th with probability 3/5, and so on).

This is known as [reservoir sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling), by the way.